# Oracle LIKE pattern match

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-like

I have 10 records in a table. Out of these records, I need to perform the following 3 operations using a single Oracle query(the reason for saying single query is that this is part of an automation framework and I need to keep a single generic query)

Operation 1: get all the 10 records

```
Select * from table_name where col01 like ('%')
<<10 records fetched>>
```

Operation 2: get records that start with the string "Tivoli"

```
Select * from table_name where col01 like ('Tivoli%')
<<1 record fetched>>
```

Operation 3: get records that DOES NOT start with "Tivoli"
            <<should give 9 records>>

I am Not able to write the query for operation 3 but I do not want to use a separate NOT LIKE clause as this would make me create a separate query altogether.

Comment: what's wrong with `not like 'Tivoli%'`? (Btw: the parentheses around the string constant are completely useless)

Comment: That means I have to create one More query with Not like. So operation 1 and 2 using LIKE and operation 3 with NOT LIKE, which is not what I want. This should be more of a generic query

Comment: If you are writing some kind of (query writing) framework, being able to negate a condition is one of the most basic things such a framework should support.

Comment: by the way, does `case sensitivity` matter for your spesific string ? e.g. can `col01` have values such as `TIVOLI..` or `tIvOli..` ?

Comment: Be aware that the first query only works for rows where col01 is not null. It doesn't retrieve any rows where col01 is null. You can work with optional parameters to deal with this correctly (e.g. `where col01 like :pattern or :pattern is null`). Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, you can use `minus` set operator :

```
Select * from table_name -- all records
minus
Select * from table_name where col01 like 'Tivoli%' 
-- records for col01 column starts with Tivoli
```

If all types of `Tivoli`( such as `TIVOLI`.. or `tIvOli` or .. ) should be included case-insensitively, then you can consider the condition as

`where lower(col01) like 'tivoli%'`

Comment: Note that `minus` removes duplicates so this might not return 9 records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select *
from table_name
where col01 not like 'Tivoli%'
```

If `col01` can be `NULL`, then you need to take that into account:

```
select *
from table_name
where col01 not like 'Tivoli%' or col01 is null;
```

Comment: `where nvl(col01,'x') not like 'Tivoli%'` might be a shorter option for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table_name where not (col01 like ('Tivoli%') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a generic query that covers all three options. Use two variables for this and set them null when you don't want to use them:

```
Select *
from table_name
where (col01 like :must_match or :must_match is null)
and (col01 not like :must_not_match or col01 is null or :must_not_match is null);
```

Or, if you want to have your framework deal with match or no match, select all rows with a flag:

```
Select
  t.*,
  case when col01 like :pattern then 'match' else 'no match' end as is_match
from table_name t;
```